# python number counter not working properly

Tags: python

I am trying to code a simple counter using the `pynput` third-party library so that when I press a key - for example, <kbd>t</kbd> - a number will go up - for example, the `x` variable shown in this code:

```
x = int(0)

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print(x + 1)

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: So what happens (or does not happen) when you run this?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `print(x + 1)`, what do you expect this to mean? If `x` is equal to `0` before this code, what do you think it will be equal to after that code? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of *x* doesn't change. It will only ever print 1. You can resolve this as follows:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

x = 0

def on_press(key):
    global x
    print(x:=x+1)

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

`x + 1` calculates the next number, but it doesn't change `x`. You need to do `x = x + 1` to change the variable.

And to make this change the variable outside the function, you have to declare it `global`.

```
def on_press(key):
    global x
    x += 1
    print(x)
```

Comment: thankyou for explaining it.